# Serilog.Exceptions Rolling Files

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2015, serilog

When a new exception is logged, a new file is created.

Scenario:
First file created: 
**log-20170602**

Files created per exceptions:
 
**log-20170602_001

log-20170602_002

log-20170602_003**

My code (C# - Visual Studio 2015 Project):

```
public class EventLogging
    {
        private readonly Logger _logger;


        public EventLogging(IOptions<LoggingOptions> logOption)
        {
            var logAccessor = logOption.Value;

            _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .WriteTo.Sink(new RollingFileSink(logAccessor.Path,
                    new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true), null, null)).CreateLogger();
        }

        public void LogError(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error(exception, message);
        }

        public void LogWarning(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Warning(exception, message);
        }
    }
```

Refer that class to avoid  writing the following code in every class:

```
_logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .WriteTo.Sink(new RollingFileSink(logAccessor.Path,
                    new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true), null, null)).CreateLogger();
```

Is there a way to prevent the files being created per exception but per new date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you creating a new logger everytime you log something?  Generally with Serilog I initialize the singleton Log instance once and use it everywhere:

At Startup:

```
Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
    .WriteTo.Sink(new RollingFileSink(logAccessor.Path,
    new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true), null, null)).CreateLogger();
```

later:

```
Serilog.Log.Error(exception, message);
```

In your case, I think if you just keep a static instance of your `_logger` instead of recreating a new one over and over, it'll solve your problem.  Or possibly if you just keep the same `RollingFileSink` and reuse it, you can get away with different loggers.

Comment: I realized that method after I noticed I was creating a new instance every time. Thanks